# Linux how to replace asterisk which only after a certain length of string

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed, escaping

I am kind of new to Linux commands. Recently I got a big files of strings(4GB)
The file format look like this.

```
1,2,http://*.example.org/
1,3,https://*.example.org/
1,4,https://*.example.org/*
1,5,https://example.org/*example
```

I want to find and replace every asterisk which only at the beginning of the line. The result I want, for example:

```
1,2,http://replaced.example.org/
1,3,https://replaced.example.org/
1,4,https://replaced.example.org/*
1,5,https://example.org/*example
```

What I have tried will replace every first occurence. Is there anyway I can do to get the result above ?

```sh
sed 's/*/replaced/' inputfile > outputfile
```

Comment: You want to replace `//*` with `//replaced`?

Comment: @Cyrus yes, basically I want to replace "*" into "replaced"

Comment: `sed 's#//\*#//replaced#'` use `#` as regex argument separator to avoid escaping `/`

Comment: @LéaGris Thank you so much, it work perfectly. One more question if you don't mind. Is there any way that I can target a certain position of strings only. For example, I want `sed` to scan only the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `://*.` with `://replaced.` using

```sh
sed 's~://\*\.~://replaced.~' file > newfile
```

Here,

- `~` is used as a regex delimiter in order to avoid escaping `/` chars
- `://\*\.` is a POSIX BRE pattern matching `://*.` substring (as `*` and `.` are special chars, they are escaped)

Note that to match an asterisk at the start of string you just need the `^` anchor. So, to match and replace a `*` at the start of a string you would use

```
sed 's/^\*/replaced/' file > newfile
```

However, none of your sample texts contain an asterisk at the start of any line.

If you plan to match and replace an asterisk at a specific position in the string you can capture a substring of the required length and replace with a backreference to the group value and the replacement text. For example:

```sh
sed 's~^\(.\{11\}\)\*~\1replaced~' file > newfile
```

will replace `*` only when it is the 12th char in the string (as is the case of the `1,2,http://*.example.org/` string).